# Несколько count() в одном запросе

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Есть таблица "department": отделы компании, ее дочерняя – post: должности, а ее дочерняя – "designations": назначения на должность. Необходимо вывести отдел, номер отдела, название должности, число действующих назначений на должности и число действующих назначений в отделе.

Если делаю такой запрос:

```
SELECT tt.*, COUNT(*) dep_total  FROM
(SELECT dep.name as depname, dep.department_id, po.name as poname, COUNT(*) as  post_total
FROM department dep
INNER JOIN post po
    ON dep.department_id=po.department_id
INNER JOIN designations des
    ON des.post_id=po.post_id AND des.leave_date is NULL
 GROUP BY dep.department_id, po.post_id
) as tt GROUP BY tt.department_id
```

, то выходит из-за группировки по отделу, показывают только одну должность в отделе:

[image: Результат запроса]

В данном случае нет должности "секретарь" из администрации.

Если такой:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.name, d.department_id, p.name , tw.post_total, tt.dep_total
FROM designations des
     INNER JOIN post p ON des.post_id=p.post_id
     INNER JOIN department d ON d.department_id=p.department_id
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT des.des_id, COUNT(*) as dep_total
                FROM department dep
                    INNER JOIN post po ON dep.department_id=po.department_id 
                    INNER JOIN designations des ON des.post_id=po.post_id AND des.leave_date is NULL
                GROUP BY dep.department_id) as tt ON tt.des_id=des.des_id
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT des.des_id, COUNT(*) as post_total
                FROM department dep
                    INNER JOIN post po ON dep.department_id=po.department_id 
                    INNER JOIN designations des ON des.post_id=po.post_id AND des.leave_date is NULL
                GROUP BY dep.department_id, des.post_id) as tw ON tw.des_id=des.des_id
WHERE des.leave_date IS NULL
```

, то так:

[image: Результат запроса2]
Структура таблиц:

department:

- department_id;
- name.

post:

- post_id;
- name;
- amount;
- salary;
- conditions;
- department_id;
- post_class_id.

designations:

- des_id;
- contract_date;
- des_date;
- leave_date;
- salary;
- staff_id;
- post_id.

Что можно еще придумать?

Comment: Исходную структуру таблиц и исходные данные для проверки запросов предлагаете придумать на основе ваших запросов и результатов ?

Comment: И не совсем ясно что вообще такое "действующие назначения на должности" и "назначения в отделе". У вас же данные в разрезе отделов И должностей. а вы хотите на против каждой должности получить что ли сумму по всем должностям в отделе ?

Comment: @Mike, Данные должны быть как на первом скрине, плюс запись: Администрация, 3, Секретарь, 1, 2. Суть в том, что есть должности (позиции) и назначения персонала на должность, уборщиков, например, может быть несколько. Также работник может уйти с должности, поэтому leave_date is NULL, дабы получить действительные назначения. Нужно что-то вроде штатного расписания. Необходимо, число действительных назначений в отделе и число действительных  назначений на конкретную должность

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если решать в лоб, то как то так:

```
SELECT dep.name as depname, dep.department_id, po.name as poname,
       COUNT(des.post_id) as  post_total,
       (
        SELECT count(1)
          FROM post po1
          JOIN designations des1 ON des1.post_id=po1.post_id AND des1.leave_date is NULL
         WHERE po1.department_id=dep.department_id
       ) dep_total
  FROM department dep
 INNER JOIN post po
    ON dep.department_id=po.department_id
  LEFT JOIN designations des
    ON des.post_id=po.post_id AND des.leave_date is NULL
 GROUP BY dep.department_id, po.post_id
```

Comment: cпасибо большое, только заменил LEFT JOIN на INNER